# Get customer address information from observer

Tags: magento-1.9, event-observer, customer, customer-address

I have created an observer event on the `customer_save_after` event. At this point I am able to get the new name. I am trying to also retrieve their default billing address. If possible bring them in as separate items like Address 1, Address 2, City, State, Zip code.

```
<?php
class Mage_Customerupdate_Model_Observer
{
    public function logUpdate(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
    {
        $customer = $observer->getEvent()->getCustomer();
        $name = $customer->getName();
        $billingaddress = $customer->getDefaultBillingAddress();
        $customerId = $customer->getId();
        $customerObject=Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->load($customerId);

         Mage::log("{$name} ({$billingaddress}) ({$customerid}) updated", null, 'customerupdate.log', true);
    }
}
?>
```

In order to get an address change maybe I have to add another event to capture that. I don't really know

At this point all I get in my results are "NAME () (ID#) updated"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get billing adress details, you can try this:

```
class Mage_Customerupdate_Model_Observer
{
    public function logUpdate(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
    {
        $customer = $observer->getEvent()->getCustomer();
        $name = $customer->getName();
        $customerId = $customer->getId();
        $billingaddress = $customer->getDefaultBillingAddress();
        // just check if there is a billing adress
        if ($billingaddress) {
            $fon = $billingaddress->getTelephone(); // or $billingaddress->getData('telephone')
            $street = $billingaddress->getStreet(); // or $billingaddress->getData('street')
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

To check all available adress data ....

```
Mage::log($billingaddress->debug(), ZEND_LOG::DEBUG, 'customer-adress.log', true);
```

Comment: Ok I have this pulling now, customer name, phone, city, State. however it returs Street as "array" And I can't get zip to give me anything, would it be getZipcode?

Comment: Cmon, try it yourself :) `Mage::log($billingaddress->debug(), ...` should show, that there is no `zipcode` data, but `postcode`. ;) If streets is an array, i guess you have at least *street_1* and *street_2* ... I dont know what you want to do at the end, but `foreach()` and `implode()` could be usefull.

Comment: Ok I see what you are saying about the customer-address.log. Now this was able to pull down the street address, but it combines the 2 lines, into 1 line, and my customerupdate.log is still coming through as an "array". Am I able to print the two lines as 2 lines?

Comment: Please check: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/9768/getstreet-endup-into-an-error-array-to-string-conversion

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can get address with event object. Try loading the customer object using customer model with Id and get the address.

```
$customerId = $customer->getId();
$customerObject=Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->load($customerId);
```

Comment: I edited my code to match your answer and am not getting any different result.

Comment: Are you getting customer id at least ?

Comment: I did get it to populate the customer Id #, how can I go from there to getting the address?

Comment: `$observer->getCustomer();` should return a `Mage_Customer_Model_Customer` object, so it should be possible to get adress details from there ...